# Java Arraylist adding functionality

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist

I have got a txt file (representing nodes and cost in the graph) which has the following format:

> A B 2
>   A C 3
>   A D 4
>   B C 2      .       .      .

I have got a class called `Node` to represent the above data.   Following is my `Node` class

```
class Node{

    Node leftchild;
    Node rightchild;
    int cost;

    public Node(Node firstchild, Node secondchild, int cost){
        this.leftchild = firstchild;
        this.rightchild = secondchild;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public Node(Node firstchild, Node secondchild) {
        this.leftchild = firstchild;
        this.rightchild = secondchild;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getChildren(){
        ArrayList<Node> childNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        if(this.leftchild != null)
        {
            childNodes.add(leftchild);
        }
        if(this.rightchild != null) 
        {
            childNodes.add(rightchild);
        }
        return childNodes;
    }

    public boolean removeChild(Node n){
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would now like to read the data (above mentioned format) from a file and store it in a three dimensional array like following

> [A] [B] [2]
>   [A] [C] [3]
>   .. So on

I have got the following method to read the data from the file and storing it in an array, but I am getting an error while adding the tokens to the arraylist.

My error is saying as: `Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Node.`

I am not sure how to fix this. Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
public Node[][][] getNodes(File file) throws IOException {
    FileReader inputHeuristic = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputHeuristic);
    String line;
    List list = new ArrayList(); 
    while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) { 
        String[] tokens = line.split(" "); 
        list.add(new Node(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]));  
    }
    bufferReader.close(); 
    return list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]); // converting list to array
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to do `new Node(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2])` when the corresponding constructor expects two `Node` and one `int` value: `public Node(Node firstchild, Node secondchild, int cost)`?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to add those types, I have googled it and found it

Comment: I wasn't sure how to add `Node` class types to the array list. I know tokens only work with integers, but how do I add a class type? I am not sure. I am kind of new to this.

Comment: Then read a tutorial. Googling around for code you don't understand is a really poor way to learn programming, even though it seems to be the most popular way these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not make much sense. You cannot change something that is a type String to a class object. Either you need to change what is being passed to the constructor or you need to change the type of the instance variables to String.

Personally I would change the Node type variables to the String Type. You will also need to parse the token[2] so its an int. i.e Integer.parseInt(token[2]);